# How to assign an iterable to a python array variable?

Tags: python, arrays

I am defining an array with 20 elements that will then ask the user to input a number for each of the elements and then it will average all the numbers they put in. However the way I am accomplishing this is very cumbersome and seems like repetitive code that can be simplified. However I am having trouble finding an answer. I would think its possible to increment the subscript after each input to avoid asking for 20 lines of input.

I've tried incorporating a start/stop/step solution. However what i did was wrong. What I tried was num[0:19:1] = int(input("type in number: "))hoping this would accomplish 3 things.

1. Start at  0
2. End at the 20th number
3. Increment by 1.

However this did not work.

```
START = input("Type start if you wan't to do this thang: ")
while START == "start":
    num = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,])
    num[0] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[1] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[2] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[3] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[4] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[5] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[6] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[7] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[8] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[9] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[10] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[11] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[12] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[13] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[14] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[15] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[16] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[17] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[18] = int(input("type in number: "))
    num[19] = int(input("type in number: "))
    average = (num[0] + num[1] + num[2] + num[3] + num[4] + num[5] + num[6] + num[7] + num[8] + num[9] + num[10] + num[11] + num[12] + num[13] + num[14] + num[15] + num[16] + num[17] + num[18]+ num[19]) / 20
    START = input("If that was wild for you, type start again, or type quit if that was lame: ")
    if START == "quit":
        break
```

Comment: Why not have a `for` loop???

Comment: @DYZ Well do you have a suggestion on how to actually do that?

Comment: The question is about elementary Python. You should read a textbook or tutorial.

Comment: @DYZ well the course I'm taking is about programming theory and the textbook only covers the things you "can" accomplish with arrays not how to do it. I posted here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues in the code

- You don't need to define your list like you are doing, you can just define an empty list like `nums=[], but here you don't need a list
- You can actually sum the numbers as you take input, instead of at the end

You can actually simplify your code a lot

1. You can take all numbers as input in a single string
2. `Split` that input string by whitespace by using [string.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.split)
3. Convert each string to integer and calculate the sum, meanwhile appending the integer to the list
4. Calculate average and print it
5. Reverse the list using slicing `nums[::-1]` and print it
6. Ask for input again

```
start = input("Type start if you wan't to do this thang: ")

#If start is inputted, check it and start the loop,
if start.lower() == 'start':
    #Start an infinite loop
    while True:
        #Take 20 numbers separated by single space
        s = input("Enter 20 numbers separated by a single space")

        #List of numbers
        nums = []
        sum = 0

        #Split the string by whitespace, iterate over it and take the sum
        for item in s.split():
            num = int(item)
            nums.append(num)
            sum += int(num)

        #Calcuate the average
        avg = sum/20
        print('Average: ',avg)

        #Reverse the numbers by using reversed function
        nums = list(reversed(nums))

        #Print numbers
        print('The numbers in reverse are ', nums)
        #Check if quit was inputted, if yes break the loop, else continue
        START = input("If that was wild for you, type start again, or type quit if that was lame: ")
        if START == "quit":
            break
```

The output will look like

```
Type start if you wan't to do this thang: start
Enter 20 numbers separated by a single space1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
Average:  3.0
The numbers in reverse are  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
If that was wild for you, type start again, or type quit if that was lame: start
Enter 20 numbers separated by a single space1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Average:  5.5
The numbers in reverse are  [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
If that was wild for you, type start again, or type quit if that was lame: quit
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! this is a good solution as well. However I discovered another need. What if I just wanted to print the numbers they gave me, and do it in reverse order?

Comment: I have updated the code @jedimilk to include how to reverse the numbers, and print them as well! Please have a look :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate your help and clearly commenting what each line does.

Comment: Thanks for the accept @jedimilk have a great day! Btw love your username lol

Comment: Hello again. I know you're probably tired of the questions but I have another one for you. Now what if I wanted to subtract each number that was input from the average of all the numbers and then print that? in normal or reverse order.

Comment: Oh and thank you about the username lol. You have a great day too.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
def iterator(n):
    START = input("Type start if you wan't to do this thang: ")
    numbers=[]
    while START == "start":
        total=0
        for i in range(0,n):
            num=int(input("type in number: "))
            total+=num
            numbers.append(num)
        print("Average : ",total/n)
        print(numbers)

        START = input("If that was wild for you, type start again, or type quit if that was lame: ")
        if START == "quit":
            break

iterator(20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now that I see it with working code. Thank you for actually being helpful rather than just downvoting me. I actually learned something.

Comment: Now how would I assign those numbers to the list numbers=[] and print them?